# Image displays text on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an image, and I style it in CSS. I need the image to display a caption when the cursor hovers over it. However, something like:

```
#image:hover {
  content:'foo';
}
```

won't work because the image is not `<p>`, right? Is there any jQuery solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give them a common parent, you can wrap the image with the parent, hide the text, then show the text relative to the parent's position when you hover the parent.

```css
figure {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
figcaption {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s, transform .25s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(0);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 3em;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  padding: 1rem;
}
figure:hover figcaption {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(720deg);
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
  <figcaption>Text</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Michael. I'm quite new to coding in HTML and CSS, I've been pretty strung on python for the past few years... What exactly do you mean by span? I'm a little confused on what it is. @MichaelCoker

Comment: Oh, is span similar to `<p>` ?

Comment: @CasparBroekhuizen yeah, a `span` is an inline element similar to the block element `p`, but they basically behave the same when absolutely positioned.